# Delete the last data entered in sorted table using variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data entry page which is basically the front end the user will interact with to enter data. The sheets with the data are hidden and inaccessible. I want them to have the option to delete the LAST record they added. I am going about this by assigning the last entered number as a variable lastReg. Then the whole row is deleted. The option for finding the last row does not apply here because the data is sorted in a table when it is added.

```
Public lastReg As Long
Sub DeleteLastReg()

Dim fcell As Range
Set regRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Range("C:C")
For Each fcell In regRange.Cells
    If fcell.Value = lastReg Then
        MsgAns = MsgBox("You are about to delete Registration Number: " & lastReg & ". Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo)
        If MsgAns = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Rows(fcell).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next fcell

End Sub
```

The error is in the:

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Rows(fcell).EntireRow.Delete

I cant figure out how to refer to that row.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registration").Rows(fcell.Row).EntireRow.Delete` should work. `fcell` is a range and not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined fcell as a cell in the relevant worksheet. So

```
fcell.EntireRow.Delete
```

should suffice

Comment: Your solution is much smoother *(+1)*. But for good measures and as a direct reply on how to use the `.Row()` method I will leave my answer as well. Still, yours is definitely better!

Comment: @Ralph  It works and, in a different scenario, might be useful to someone looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

`fcell` is a range. Yet, the `row()` function requires a number. So, this should work just fine:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registration").Rows(fcell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
```